# Angular data binding issue

Tags: angular

```
<body ng-app="myAPP">
<div ng-controller="employeeCtrl"> 
    <table style="border:1px solid gray">
        <tr>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Employee Address</th>
            <th>Employee Salary</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
            <td>
                {{emp.EmployeeName}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{emp.EmployeeAddress}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{emp.EmployeeSalary}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
var myAPP = angular.module('myAPP', []);

myAPP.controller('employeeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {    
    $scope.employees = "";
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/Employee/GetEmployee'
    }).then(function (result) {
        $scope.employees = result;
    }, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }); 
});
```

using angular 1.6.6 version data binding is not working though it returns results from http get method.

Comment: add your controller code also

Comment: Provide `employeeCtrl` inside question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the data property of the response, change your controller method as follows, and **`$scope.employees`** is an **`array`** not a **`string`**,

```
var myAPP = angular.module('myAPP', []);

myAPP.controller('employeeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {    
    $scope.employees = [];
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/Employee/GetEmployee'
    }).then(function (result) {
        $scope.employees = result.data;
    }, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to iterate through a string. It should be

```
$scope.employees = [];
```

or

```
$scope.employees = null;
```

but not an empty string.

And later `employees` becomes an HTTP response. Once again something that you can't iterate on. If the **body** of the response is indeed an array, then it should be

```
$scope.employees = result.data;
```